# Which query is more efficient?

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, optimization

I currently have two tables called 'names' and 'accounts'.  I need to select all the names where the account is enabled.  So I can do this one of two ways but I am wondering which would be faster and most efficient?

The first way is to select all accounts that are enabled, then in a separate query have a where clause with these accounts (pseudocode):

```
    SELECT account_id FROM accounts WHERE enabled=1;
```

then

```
    SELECT * FROM names WHERE account_id IN (account_id_list);
```

OR I can do a simple join on the tables:

```
    SELECT * FROM names JOIN accounts USING account_id WHERE enabled=1;
```

The name table will be around 10-25k rows and will also be running on a mobile device (Android) using SQLite.

Thanks!

Comment: use the command `EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN` and find out: http://www.sqlite.org/eqp.html

Comment: Didnt think about that...that's probably the best answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

nested selects are MUCH better than joins, so just combine first two queries into one:

```
SELECT * FROM names WHERE account_id IN (
SELECT account_id FROM accounts WHERE enabled=1);
```

Comment: I can't find anything about SQLite being much better at subqueries than joins. Do you have any info on that?

Comment: No I don't have any info, only experience with SQLite (and the difference is more drastic the more joins you have).

Answer (score 0):

Considering that the query is quite simple and a lot of the work the SQL engine has to do in the first case is just formatting/passing data to your program just to have it sent back right away and have to parse it again, the second version should be quite a bit more efficient (and save your program some work too)

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT * FROM names  WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM accounts WHERE account_id = names.account_id AND enabled=1);`